# Displaying results from a union query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problems echoing results from my query using union.

I want to create a student cumulative result where the sum total scores for first term, second term and third term are collated.

However, I don't seem to be getting it right in terms of displaying the results on a table.

Query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT mp.id, mp.student_id, mp.class_id, mp.section_id, mp.ft_ca1, mp.ft_ca2, mp.ft_ca3, mp.ft_ca4, mp.ft_ca5, mp.ft_ca6, mp.ft_project, mp.ft_affective, mp.ft_psychomotor, mp.ft_exam, mp.ft_tot_score as total, mp.created_at, mp.modified_at
                FROM ftscores_primary mp
                WHERE mp.class_id = 7 AND mp.student_id = 23 AND mp.section_id = 1 AND mp.subject_id = 8  AND mp.session_id = 16
                UNION
               SELECT st.id, st.student_id, st.class_id, st.section_id, st.ca1, st.ca2, st.ca3, st.ca4, st.ca5, st.ca6, st.project, st.affective, st.psychomotor, st.exam, st.tot_score, st.created_at, st.modified_at
                FROM scores_primary st
                WHERE st.class_id = 7 AND st.student_id = 23 AND st.section_id = 1 AND st.subject_id = 8  AND st.session_id = 16
                UNION
                SELECT tt.id, tt.student_id, tt.class_id, tt.section_id, tt.h_ca1, tt.h_ca2, tt.h_ca3, tt.h_ca4, tt.h_ca5, tt.h_ca6, tt.h_project, tt.h_affective, tt.h_psychomotor, tt.h_exam, tt.h_tot_score, tt.created_at, tt.modified_at
                FROM hscores_primary tt
                WHERE tt.class_id = 7 AND tt.student_id = 23 AND tt.section_id = 1 AND tt.subject_id = 8  AND tt.session_id = 16");
                 $totScores = $query->result_array();
```

when I print out `$totScores`, I get:

```
Array ( [0] => 
    Array ( [id] => 85 
            [student_id] => 23 
            [class_id] => 7 
            [section_id] => 1 
            [ft_ca1] => 20 
            [ft_exam] => 65 
            [total] => 85
) 
[1] => Array ( 
          [id] => 696 
          [student_id] => 23 
          [class_id] => 7 
          [section_id] => 1 
          [ft_ca1] => 18 
          [ft_exam] => 63 
          [total] => 81
) [2] => Array ( 
          [id] => 594 
          [student_id] => 23 
          [class_id] => 7 
          [section_id] => 1 
          [ft_ca1] => 27 
          [ft_exam] => 60 
          [total] => 87 
) 
)
```

Then I did this to display the `[total]` on a table.

```
  <?php
foreach ($totScores as $totvalue) { ?>
                                         
<tr>
<td><?php echo $CI->GetSubjectNameWithID($totvalue->subject_id); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $totvalue[0]['total']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $totvalue[1]['total']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $totvalue[2]['total']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

I did a var_dump on `$totvalue[0]['total']` and I get `NULL`.

I guess I'm stuck and need help. Thanks

Comment: _"I did a var_dump on $totvalue[0]['total'] and I get NULL."_ - of course you do, because `$totvalue` is referring to one of your sub-arrays already. This should be `$totvalue['total']`.

Comment: And `$totvalue->subject_id` makes no sense whatsoever - you have arrays here all over, not a single _object_ in sight anywhere.

Comment: I don't see how that query can produce that array (your fetching way more columns than you get in that array)? And you're not even fetching any column named `subject_id` at all. You're using it in your WHERE statements, but you're not fetching it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach($totvalue as $key => $data){
  ?><td><?php echo $data['total']; ?></td><?php
}
?>
```

Hope this will help you